# Any benefits or downsides to including external scripts via PHP file include vs script src?

Tags: javascript, php, include

Is there any benefit or downside to including `.js` files via PHP vs. `<script src="" />`? Though approach 1 below would result in fewer HTTP requests, is it worthwhile to do this? For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <!-- Approach 1 -->
      <?php
      echo '<script>',
           file_get_contents('script1.js'),
           file_get_contents('script2.js'),
           file_get_contents('script3.js'),
           '</script>';
      ?>

      <!-- Approach 2 -->
      <script src="script1.js"></script>
      <script src="script2.js"></script>
      <script src="scriptn.js"></script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: If it's the amount of HTTP requests that troubles you (and that _is_ something I have to deal with at work, yet I don't think it's much of an issue outside of it) then just use any of the millions and billions of JS build tools to concatenate them so you only fetch one (or few) on page load. The scripts can further be minified to make the transfer even faster. No need to do the extra processing each time you get a request - if 1000 people hit your server, suddenly you do 1000 times more processing instead of just serving static files (which should be minimal problem).

Comment: Another thing I can add is when you ask `is it worthwhile to do this?` it suggests you don't actually know. And if you don't actually know, then it's not a problem. And if it's not a problem, you're most likely trying to prematurely optimise something.

Comment: Not thinking about optimizing anything; the thought occurred to me and I'm just interested in learning and seeing what others think. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @vlaz could you perhaps convert your first comment into an answer and elaborate on or reference one or more of these build tools you mentioned? I think it would benefit the community.

Comment: OK, let me give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the amount of HTTP requests shouldn't be that much of a concern. I'll start this with saying that you only need to specifically target it, if you find it's a bottleneck.

With that said, there is merit in keeping the requests low. In particular users with high latency will benefit the most - they might need to wait for 1-2 seconds *or more* to start downloading a file. Since latency is not strictly coupled with bandwidth, you can have somebody with a fast connection but with a big startup time.

However, putting JS code directly in the HTML you serve by including the files with PHP is a bit counterproductive - it means that you do more processing with each hit. With 1000 people simultaneously visiting will mean more than 1000 time the processing needed, since for each hit you will need to retrieve multiple files, extract the contents and put them in the request. It may be fast, but with a lot of people visiting, you will eventually hit performance issues there. Sure, caching will help but it only goes so far.

So, the main thing you might want to target is keep low amount of requests, don't do too much processing and be able to serve a lot of files. Since servers are rather good at *serving* content, you have the last point ticked off if you just keep more static files. And since static files don't require that much processing, you have the second to last ticked off if you solve that. So, what about the first one?

Enter JavaScript build tools. Now, there are many *many* of them but, in general, they do the same things only with somewhat different approaches. In fact, for the most part they can be thought of glorified bunch of scripts as they bundle up some functionality and allow you to add more as per your needs. You can very easily make your own with any scripting language of your choice. However, don't let the label "glorified scripts" fool you - JavaScript build tools are really good at what they do, and they make your projects more presentable for the web.

Broadly, the functionality they would support (nearly) out of the box would be

1. Pre-process your files and derive others

   - TypeScript files can be compiled to JavaScript
   - JavaScript files written in ES6 can be transpiled into compatible ES5 code
   - Less/Sass templates can be compiled to normal CSS
   - etc
2. Optimise resources

   - JavaScript files can be concatenated
   - JavaScript files can additionally (or instead) be minified
   - Images can be optimised
   - etc
3. Performed Static and active checks on your codebase

   - running linters such as JSCS, JSHint, ESLint, CSSLint, etc.
   - running any tests
4. Produce a deliverable

   - exclude files that aren't needed - e.g., test code
   - include any amount of files needed for the actually run - e.g., JavaScript code, which was potentially the output from one of the previous steps
   - bundle the files together - either just moving them to a new directory or zipping them or otherwise giving you the one thing that *is* your webapp

So, build tools can do a lot of stuff. There is even more functionality they support  and most will allow you to provide anything custom you want on top. However, this is a solid core of what a webapp will need. The things you are interested in are in step 2 - concatenating JavaScript files is exactly what it sounds like - if you have **file1.js**, **file2.js** and **file3.js** you will produce **file123.js** which includes all three. This means that instead of three HTTP requests, your users only need to make one. The second thing that can be done is minification which takes JavaScript code and tries to reduce the size as much as possible, so they are easier to transfer via the internet. For example this code (deliberately verbose):

```
/**
 * Function that can produce the sum of any numbers
 * @param {number} inputOne - the first number to add
 * @param {number} inputTwo - the second number to add
 * @return {number} the combination of both of the above
 */
function add(inputOne, inputTwo) {
   //using JavaScript mathematical operation
   var output = inputOne + inputTwo;
   return output;
}
```

Will be turned to this:

```
function add(a,b){var c=a+b;return c}
```

So, by pre-concatenating and pre-minifying your JavaScript code, you will be serving much smaller requests and will be doing much less processing for each hit, since all you need to do is serve static files.

Here are but very few of the build tools available, for it is hard to keep up with all of them:

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) - it is quite powerful and configuration driven.
[Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) - equally powerful but defining its workflow in terms of "tasks" which are very small JavaScript manipulations.
[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) - focused on just bundling up your app and producing your build artefact.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer approach 2, it would result in more http requests (but only one time, other times it will be cached on the browser)
Approach 1: If your have 10 scripts of 3Kb, you are loading 30kb every page load.

Answer (score 0):

By loading your scripts inline, and especially in the `<head>` you are causing the page to execute the javascript and therefore block the rest of the page from loading.

If you use the `<script>` tag (which you should put at the end of the `<body>` tag, you can always have them load using the `async` or `defer` attribute, and you can also leverage browser caching.

Comment: Right, I agree with loading scripts at the end as you mentioned. Let's ignore that part. Regardless of where the inline loading takes place, what's the comparison with the PHP approach?

Answer (score 0):

Less HTTP requests but you do more processing (IO too in this case) for every request done. It's just better to serve the script as a static resource, so the browser can cache it.